# Javascript moment date conversion & formatting issue

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I am using "moment" for date conversion and formatter. I have input as a date  in this format `"2016-06-08T08:29:54.000Z"` and i want to format it using moment in this format `format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")`

When i am trying to convert this date `"2016-06-08T08:29:54.000Z"` into above format i got this answer `"June 8th 2016, 1:59:54 pm"`.

I am little confuse that the conversion of date is proper or not

Adding to this...
I have one more different date in different format

**"Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016"**

Whenever i am trying to convert this date in **new Date("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016")**
it is giving me an error says invalid date and i also tried **moment("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016") and moment(new Date("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016"))** it is giving the same error

This issue is only in IE, in chrome it is working fine.
i want the result in this format **moment("Tue Jun 21 10:52:32 +0000 2016").format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not sure about the this you can just use:

```
moment("2016-06-08T08:29:54.000Z").format("LLL")
```

which is a preset format of what you are trying to do and returns

> "June 8, 2016 11:29 AM"

Please note that the time is transformed to the clients GMT due to the browsers time.

Further reading about this time format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC

Comment: thank you, see when i am converting this date i am getting this output **"June 8th 2016, 1:59:54 pm"** and in your answer **"June 8, 2016 11:29 AM"**, so which one is correct and why there is a change in time i am not understanding.

Comment: Its not about correct or incorrect, its based on the users location. Originally its UTC and it converts it to your local time. Added a link to read.

Comment: Additional documentaiton on how moment converts ISO 8601 format can be found in the docs here: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/ or in this blog post I wrote: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/